# Sharepoint-hosted app: Access site columns belonging to host site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, site-column, app, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have a sharepoint-hosted app containing a custom list. On the host site collection where I am deploying this app, there are several custom site columns.

In my app, I want to access these site columns and include as columns in my custom list.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I created a site column called Test in the Host Web and then I used this code to add it to a list in the App Web.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var fields = web.get_availableFields();
    var testField = fields.getByTitle("Test");

    var lci = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
    lci.set_title("Test");
    lci.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.genericList);
    var list = web.get_lists().add(lci);

    list.get_fields().add(testField);

    context.executeQueryAsync(success, fail);

    function success() {
        var message = jQuery("#message");
        message.text("List added");
    }

    function fail(sender, args) {
        alert('Error:' + args.get_message());
    }
});
```